# How to resolve 'Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory' in Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I want to resolve an error in Nodejs 
  I have the following code -

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var url = require('url');
var path = require('path');

function ensureDirectoryExistence(pathname) {
    var dirname = path.dirname(pathname);
    if (fs.existsSync(dirname)) {
      return true;
    }
    ensureDirectoryExistence(dirname);
    fs.mkdirSync(dirname);
  }

http.createServer( function (request, response) {  
   var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
   console.log(pathname);

    console.log("Request for " + pathname + " received.");

   fs.readFile(pathname.substr(1), function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
         console.log(err);
         response.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
      }else {   
         response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});    

         response.write(data.toString());       
      }
      response.end();
   });   
}).listen(8081);

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8081/');
```

I am getting the error

> Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8081/
>       pow!
>       /index.htm
>       Request for /index.htm received.
>       { Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
>       'C:\Users\Ryuzaki\Desktop\Intern\watson\index.htm'
>         errno: -4058,
>         code: 'ENOENT',
>         syscall: 'open',
>         path: 'C:\Users\Ryuzaki\Desktop\Intern\watson\index.htm' }

Please tell me how to resolve this error? 
I am unable to create the Path or Directory.

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please take some time to read the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. To summarize you're supposed to first try it yourself and come here only when facing an issue in your code, showing us this code and explaining clearly the situation. Not doing this will result in your question to be deleted, possibly very fast...

Comment: I do not have a code as I don't know how to start

Comment: Then SO is definitely not the right place to come now... And actually you'll have a hard time with such a broad question to get an answer on any SE site at all. If you're so clueless about where to start, maybe you will actually have to hire a contractor to perform what you want to do...

Comment: okay i will try myself. just keep this question for a few hours in case anyone is interested

Comment: There's very few chances that this question will even be kept for the next hour, but not harm done: just come back later one and create another question following the advise/rules on the "how to ask" page.

Comment: i will have a code put up within a few hours

Answer (score 1):

What your code is doing is this:
a. It takes the url path. Example from `http://localhost:8081/index.html` it will take out the `/index.htm`.

b. You are then using `String.substr()` method to remove the leading `/`. So your path actually becomes `index.htm`.

c. You are then using the `fs` module to read `index.htm`  and serve it.
This is being read from the directory where you are running the node process. Which seems to be `C:\Users\Ryuzaki\Desktop\Intern\watson\index.htm`, however what the error is complaining is that here is no index.htm file here.
So what you need to do create index.htm file in this path `C:\Users\Ryuzaki\Desktop\Intern\watson\index.htm` and then it will be served.

**Note: The code you have written is not suitable for production/live systems as it is basically giving you raw access to the machines file system.**